# RxJava in trading engine

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'll write in pseudocode to avoid unnecessary boilerplate. I'm new to Rx but i really want to use it instead of Features and similar stuff...

this is a simplified model of trading engine

we have a  which provides all the streams of events (observables) that one might be interested in like

```
market.updateStream // stream of orderbook update events
```

we have so called s those will subscribe to requried streams and "react" when any change occures like this

```
market.updateStream.subscribe(bot1.marketUpdateAction)
market.updateStream.subscribe(bot2.marketUpdateAction)
```

we might have MANY bots that will subscribe to ONE market and each of those will either start calculating or ignore the change event.

now that we have N bots reacting to 1 event, we need someone to compare their calculations and decide which one is the most profitable also if some bot is slowing down and is exceeding limit of time we are ready to wait, we skip it and proceed to comparision and execution... for that we have a botController which is subscribed to all bots events so that it knows when a bot decided to react to an event... like this

```
bot1.calculationStream.subscribe(botController.botActivityAction)
```

bot will in its turn emit 2 different events (*calculationStarted* and *calculationEnded* which contains actual result)

when a bot emits event that its started to calculate (this happens if market event is in bot interest so not all bots will emit start event) botController shall do the following, start counting time with the very first bot started event, and await for all bots that emit similar event, if registered bots finish early, comparision starts immidiately...

Sorry if the question is too abstract but i dont really see how do i implement botControllers behaviour with RxJava... Any toughts are appreciated... there are so many rx transformations that i dont really know what can i use there.

---

UPDATE

Suppose our controller is subscribed to N bots events and each bot can emit 2 events (STARTED, COMPLETED)...

now when controller gets first STARTED event its starts the countdown T, while T time is not expired it will accept new events from bots, when T is expired or all bots return COMPLETED event it does some calculation and returns a single result...

the part i dont understand : rx as far as i know is handling each event in isolation thus the safety from tipical concurrency problems, now that i have several events that are tied to each other i dont see how can i do this using rx... I just need some guidance on this.

Comment: What is your question? I _think_ you're wondering how to build a "bot controller" that will subscribe to N observables, then take all available results after T time, do something with them, and then pass that on?

Comment: Almost yes, when first "botStartedCalculation" emits botController registers that bot and knows that this bot shall return "botResult" (or be ignored if T time is passed and nothing arrives from that bot), my question/problem is that i dont really understand how to implement such behaviour using Rx transformations, i'd need something like pseudocode that could give me a clue if this is possible with Rx... I'll update the question to explain problem more clearly...

Comment: I've even tried to find someone to help me at hackhands but no one responded :(

Answer (score 4):

I don't fully understand your problem, but here are some design ideas to show you how to think the "Rx-way":

I wouldn't subscribe bots, but rather, they should be a `map` or `flatMap` on the update stream, so that they transform the stream of updates into a stream of their answers.

I'd make a `BotAnswer` class with 4 subclasses: `Result`, `NotInterested`, `Timeout`, `BotError`.

Then for each bot:

```
Observable<BotAnswer> bot1Answers = market.updateStream.flatMap(event -> 
  Observable.just(event).map({ if (event is interesting)
    return new Result(doBotCalculations())
  else
    return new NotInterested()
  })
  .timeout(T, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .onErrorResumeNext(
     error -> if (error instanceof TimeoutException)
        return Observable.just(new Timeout())
      else
        return Observable.just(new BotError(error))
   )
)
```

And the controller would do a `zip` on all bot answers:

```
Observable.zip(bot1Ansers, bot2Answers, ... (a1, a2, ...) -> {
  // compare the answers a1, a2, ... do some calculations, return result
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll start with this.

Comment: But we have a huge problem here, each bot will start its own timeout calculation... but we need that controller does that starting with first bot... you think its doable with RX?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i've come up with...

each bot subsribes for market updates,
when market is updated, bot starts computing,
when its finished its emiting completion event, 
if its getting termination event from supervisor its stoping computation, if its getting another market update its terminating current execution and starts over...

supervisor  subsribes for market updates too,
when its getting one its expecting all bots computation results (no result is also a result :), 
if some bot is taking too long its ingnoring him by sending termination event (and counts that bot as returning no result),
as soon as it gets all the bots results its aware of it starts comparing them and emitting the final value to its subscriber,
if it gets another market update while executing it will terminate its computation and start over (waiting for bots)...

Regarding implementation, Bot will manage to handle proper concurrent access to its methods like (start, terminate), as well as Supervisor, eventually those objects ensure no unsafe operation can be done with the object by concurrent execution, using traditional synchronization, but main flow of what triggers what and what happens around is controlled by Rx...

Note that timeout is controlled by supervisor in this case...

Do i miss something here? maybe i'm doing something wrong if i have to use traditional synchronization in conjunction with rx?